# google spreadsheets: Compare date with dates in a cell range

Tags: google-sheets

I have a date in cell `B1` and list of Dates in `A1:A100`. 
I would like to get for `B1` the cell in `A1:A100` where the date has the smallest difference in time.
As you can see in the example, the closest Date to `B1` from `A1:A100` is in cell `A2`.

```
  A          B          C
1  15.4.2011 03.3.2011  A2
2  01.3.2011 
3  11.7.2011
4  09.2.2011
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the dates which are nearest to the date in cell B1, try the following formula in some free cell:

```
=arrayformula(filter(A:A,abs(A:A-B1)=min(abs(A:A-B1))))
```

And to get the row number in which the nearest date is, try the following formula:

```
=arrayformula(match(filter(A:A,abs(A:A-B1)=min(abs(A:A-B1))),A:A,0))
```

And finally try the following formula for your desired result:

```
=arrayformula(address(match(filter(A:A,abs(A:A-B1)=min(abs(A:A-B1))),A:A,0),1,4,true))
```

[image: Screenshot]